# Autocomplete Search Boxes For Large Datasets on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm completely new to Google App Engine, and I want to verify my understanding of some things.  The project that I'm working on involves providing a type ahead autocomplete search box, e.g. JQuery autocomplete, for a very large dataset.

Now, if GAE wasn't in the picture, my general idea is to store the dataset in a NoSQL database, have a distributed cache in front of that, and have the web page run against the cache.

1. I like the one stop shop approach of GAE, but is the appengine datastore appropriate for a couple million entries or is it more appropriate to use the standalone datastore service?
2. The memcache included with appengine only seems to support "gets" with the exact key.  I'm used to being able to submit a query similar to "like A%" which will return all of the items that begin with "A".  In other words, if the user types "A" in the search box, I want to a (reasonably limited) list of all the items starting with "A" not the one entry that exactly matches "A".  Is memcache going to work for this?  If not, will datastore be fast enough without a cache?
3. I have a prototype running on my local machine using the SDK.  Everything works great.  When I deploy the code to App Engine, it doesn't seem like typing in the autocomplete box is actually sending anything that is being received by the app.  In the Google Cloud Shell, I can clearly see the app receiving GET and PUT when I click on Form buttons or go to a new URL, but when I type in the autocomplete box, nothing happens.  HTML code shown.  Ideas?

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Demo</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>

     <center>
       <form action='demo' method='post' >
       <form action='' method='post' >
           <p><label>Product Name:  </label><input type='text' name='product' value='' class='auto'></p>
       <input type='submit' value='Search'/>
       </form>
     </center>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {

       //autocomplete
       $(".auto").autocomplete({
           source: "demo",
           minLength: 1
       });
   });
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```